# Create a List depending the Area, Excel or Google Sheets

Tags: excel, list, if-statement, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a list in a different sheet depending on the area, so basically I have a dropdown to select 3 areas, and depending on that I want to generate a sheet with all the information from that contact, this is my list:

[image]

I tried to paste this data but was not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FILTER()` or `QUERY()` both will work in this case. Try-

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A2:C6,Sheet1!C2:C6=F2)
=QUERY(Sheet1!A2:C,"where C='" &F2 & "'")
```

[image]